# Interrupted time series with ARIMA in R - effect of the intervention

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to estimate the effect of an intervention in a interrupted time series analysis. I used an ARIMA model with the package TSA and created a dummy variable for the pre and post-intervention time. Here is an example with the airmiles data included in the TSA package.

```
data(airmiles)
bin.int <- ts(c(rep(0,68),rep(1,45)))
air.m2=arimax(log(airmiles),order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=12),
          xreg=data.frame(bin.int),
          method='ML')
air.m2
coeftest(air.m2)
```

When I used the argument xreg, I understand I fit a coefficient for the effect of X. If X is a dummy variable (0 before and 1 after the intervention), this method estimates the effect as a level change. How may I estimate both a level change and/or a slope change with an ARIMA model ?

Do I have to use the transfer function with autoregressive and moving average parameters ?

Thank you.

François

Comment: Take a look at [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168803/171783).